# Run windows apps (like VSCode) in wsl

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed several apps in Windows only to later find out that they can't be called from WSL terminal. I don't want to install apps again in WSL. Is there a way to run apps like VSCode (already installed in Windows) in WSL?

Comment: wsl is essentially an isomorphic box with linux file and directory structure, which only resembles the structure of windows file and directory structure. This way seems to me not very correct, since you may encounter other problems associated with such a startup procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i find WSL awesome (Im using WSL 1), it integrates really well with windows 10 and ubuntu. I spend most of my day in there.

I have set up alias to a few windows applications that i use a lot. Inside your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc you need to add something like these to the top:

```
alias webstorm="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/JetBrains/WebStorm/bin/webstorm64.exe"
alias subl="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe"
alias chrome="/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

Following this pattern vs code would be something like:

```
alias code="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/Code.exe"
```

OR

```
alias code="/mnt/c/Users/damo/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS Code/bin/code.exe
```

Depending on your install location. Check your alias with `alias` from within wsl.

The alternative is to ensure that your path contains the directory of the application in question. Check your path with `echo $PATH`

But when i installed VS code it actually put itself in the WSL path, have you tried just typing `code .` does that not open vs code in your current location?

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info. I'll do that

Comment: Damo - is it possible to render these Windows apps inside GUI-enabled WSL?